# Does Google disclose stable release version dates for Android development tools in advance?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Is there an approximate timeline for the stable release of Android Studio 3.0 / the gradle plugins that come with it?

Is that something that Google normally makes public in advance?

I have tried to find information all over developer.android.com, the Android Studio docs / blog / twitter, and non-official channels but I am only seeing information about betas.

I am wondering if this is even something they disclose, since some versions of the gradle plugin have stayed in beta for a very long time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a customer service question.

Comment: Thanks for at least giving an explanation.
So the rest of Android development questions (yes, customer support for a corporation) are ok, but not this one?
This is a relevant question to me from an Android library developer's perspective, since there have been changes to the details of including aar's inbetween the different beta versions.
It's pretty disheartening to me that people will happily ignore good questions for years on StackOverflow because they take more time to answer, but monitoring a tag for things you can downvote can generate so many negative votes in a matter of minutes.

Comment: Android development questions are not "customer support for a corporation" any more than are questions about Rails or Oracle databases. However, asking about *product release plans* could readily be considered to be off-topic, since questions about product release plans are not questions about programming. Hence, I am not the least bit surprised that you collected a lot of downvotes and close-votes.

Comment: See some examples of off-topic questions [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company). Note: `I voted to close != downvoted`. However do not feel discourage about the votes cuz sometimes it helps you understand things that are not supposed to do, feel free to ask another question but make sure this time that you have read the rules. Good luck :)

Answer (score 4):

> Is there an approximate timeline for the stable release of Android Studio 3.0 / the gradle plugins that come with it?

It should be released sometime before [the heat death of the universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_death_of_the_universe).

If you are looking for something more precise than that, I doubt that *Google* knows, let alone anyone else.

> Is that something that Google normally makes public in advance?

No.